# Panda Python - Calculating what percentage of values are true and false out of total in boolean column

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have a boolean value with True and False.

When I run a `value_counts()` like this

```
df['column'].value_counts()
```

I receive the following:

```
True     10718
False     1105
Name: column, dtype: int64
```

Is there a way to calculate what % of the total is true and what % is false?

Something like this:

```
True     91%
False    09%
Name: column, dtype: int64
```

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do with

```
df['yourcolumns'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).astype(str)+'%'
```

Comment: Oh thank you, that last part with the '%' really fixes it too!

Answer (score 5):

I was notified that it is as simple as

```
df['column'].value_counts(normalize=True)
```